# How to share session variables between subdomains EXCEPT one

Tags: php, subdomain

I am trying to configure my project for session variables to be shared between the primary domain and its subdomains. But I would like a specific subdomain not to compare the session variables, but the session variables of that subdomain itself.

It was placed in the main folder that contains the main domain htaccess -> `php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com`

The idea is that there are session variables shared between subdomains for MainFolder and different ones for a secondFolder that refers to a specific subdomain specific.example.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you may solve this by changing the session name into your specific.example.com.

```
session_name("SpecificPHPSESSID");
```

Read http://www.php.net/session_name for more info about this.